# Starter "Hello World" React Project Gives Empty Page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, create-react-app

I am new in React.js development and I tried a simple hello world page but I got an empty page and also I didn't get any error.

I use `create-react-app` for creating this project. After creating the project,I started the localhost with `npm` command and I deleted all files in the `src` folder. Than I created `index.js` and `HelloWorld.jsx` files in the `src` folder. Then I write these codes in these files. And I got empty page.
But I want to write `Hello Mark` in the page. Why does it code give me an empty page?

`index.js` file:

```
import React,{ Component } from 'react';

import HelloWorld from './HelloWorld';

class index extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="index">
        <HelloWorld name="Mark" />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default index;
```

`HelloWorld.jsx` file:

```
import React,{ Component } from 'react';

const HelloWorld = (props) => (
  <div>
    <h2>Hello <em>{props.name}</em></h2>
  </div>
);

export default HelloWorld;
```

Comment: You are importing ReactDOM, are you using `render`?

Comment: @BoyWithSilverWings it doesn't change anything. But, it's true , I don't use it and I delete the import ReactDOM statement.

Comment: Wait, are you not using `ReactDOM.render()` at all?

Comment: @Chris yes, I don't use. You can see my edited post.(There isn't a ReactDOM import statement.)

Comment: You have to use `ReactDOM.render()` to see the output rendered to the screen. that is what determines the root component

Comment: ...and actually renders the output

Comment: this: https://github.com/LondonAppDev/demo-react-hello/blob/master/src/index.js

Comment: @RandyCasburn Oh okay, I understand that there must be `ReactDOM.render()` in the every`index.js` and so this is an obligation, isn't it?

Comment: @termittermit, check mine or Randy's answer.

Comment: You changed the fundamental layout of the application from the template you started with. The `index.js` file only loads the other resources and renders them. The Code in your `index.js` file is from that example's `app.js` file. When you combed them, you deleted the necessary `render()` step.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, so a few things:

First of all, change the name of your root component from `index` to `Index`. React components should start with a capital letter.

Then, you **have to** use `ReactDOM.render()` at the root level. This is what actually initiates the rendering and reconciliation process of all subcomponents.

```
import React,{ Component } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

import HelloWorld from './HelloWorld';

class Index extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="index">
        <HelloWorld name="Mark" />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Index />, document.getElementById("app"));
```

Note that you also need an `index.html` file with a `div` in the body with an `id` attribute that matches the selector above (in this example "`app`").

Answer (score 0):

Your import statement is incorrect. When using a local import you must provide the file extension.

**Change**

```
import HelloWorld from './HelloWorld';
```

**To**

```
import HelloWorld from './HelloWorld.jsx';
```

EDIT: As BoyWithSilverWings points out, the app was never rendered into the DOM. You must take this step. Here is the code from the HelloWorld example you've drawn from:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker';

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
registerServiceWorker();
```

When you moved that to your index file you then removed the render call.

Comment: it doesn't change anything.